# "DeploymentLimitExceededException" on ECS Service (AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-code-deploy, http-status-code-400, error-code

I got the error when I created a `service` in `ECS`.

[image]

As the error says, the error happens in `CodeDeploy`.

```
The CodeDeploy deployment was not successful.
CodeDeploy The blue/green deployment was not successfully started 
for the service: The Deployment Group 'DgpECS-blogClu-test' already
has an active Deployment 'd-6C9HNEPDA' (Service: AmazonCodeDeploy; 
Status Code: 400; Error Code: DeploymentLimitExceededException;
Request ID: 5d4984d5-29fa-4681-97e4-acfa54b55e2b; Proxy: null)
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `CodeDeploy`. Then, check "`Deployment group deployment history`" at `Application`.

[image]

`One deployment group` is already running so you got the error because you cannot run `multiple deployment groups` at the same time.

[image]

You can stop it or wait for it to finish. Then, you can run `another deployment group`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can do the same thing explain in Kai's answer using aws cli as well -

```
aws deploy stop-deployment --deployment-id d-A1B2C3111
```

if you want to list all the failed deployment Id, then -

```
aws deploy list-deployments 
    --application-name <Application> 
    --create-time-range start=2023-08-19T00:00:00,end=2023-08-20T00:00:00 
    --deployment-group-name <DeploymentGroup> 
    --include-only-statuses Failed
```